# Finding a function $K$ in an equation with a fix-point argument or a power series

Tags: fixed-point-theorems

I have the following equation where I look for a function $L:\mathbb R\to \mathbb R$
$$
f\big(L(x_1)-L(x_2)\big)+c f''\big(L(x_1)-L(x_2)\big) = f(x_1-x_2)
$$
Here $f$ is an at least odd smooth function from $\mathbb R\to \mathbb R$, c is a constant. $f$ is also monotone increasing. I guess existence of $L$ is equivalent to the similar question (interchanging the left and right side)
or perhaps the more easier version (but I guess equivalent)
$$
f(x_1-x_2)+c f''(x_1-x_2) = f(K(x_1)-K(x_2)).
$$
Since $f$ is monotone increasing and continuous I can write the latter as
$$
f^{-1}\big(f(x_1-x_2)+c f''(x_1-x_2)\big) = K(x_1)-K(x_2).
$$
We can add additional assumptions to $f$ it and I am asking myself, when does a function $K$ (or $L$) exists to solve this equation? In the end I don't even know how to start since it is not something like $f\circ K$, to be more precise, I have no clue at all.

Do I need a variaction of Inverse/Implicit Function Theorem? What about power series approach, assuming $K$ and $f$ having a series-representation on $\mathbb R$ I can calculate my $a_n$ recursively but what does this say about existence?

Any other trick? In which direction should I look? Thanks for all tips in advance

Additional information, this is a special case of my problem [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3973587/variation-of-the-inverse-function-theorem-for-multiple-variables-to-find-existen)